# Pasar parámetro de tipo DataTable a SP genera excepción: "Los datos de cadena o binarios se truncarían. Se terminó la instrucción."

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, sql

Les explico el error que me está dando la siguiente consulta. Implementé un procedimiento almacenado que recibe un parámetro de tipo tabla. El procedimiento almacenado es básicamente un insert a otra tabla con los datos que vienen en dicho parámetro(tipo tabla).

Sin embargo cuando hago el "ExecuteSqlCommand" me salta este error: "Los datos de cadena o binarios se truncarían. Se terminó la instrucción."

El método va algo así:

```
public void Insert(List<object> objs)
{
     var dt = new DataTable();
     //Agrego las columnas

     //Intenté pasar un rango de filas con objs.GetRange(0, 1000) pero el error persiste
     foreach (object obj in objs)
     {
         //Agrego filas a dt
         dt.Rows.Add(obj.campo_1, obj.campo_n);
     }

     var parametro = new SqlParameter("@nombre_de_parametro_en_sp", SqlDbType.Structured)
     {
         Value = dt,
         TypeName = "[dbo].[tipo_de_dato_en_bd]"
     };

     using (var context = new MiContexto())
     {
         context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC nombre_de_sp_en_bd @nombre_de_parametro_en_sp", parametro);
     }
}
```

Lo curioso es que al implementar un insert individual por cada registro de la lista no da ningún error. Los valores son exactamente los mismos en ambos casos.

```
public void Insert(List<object> objs)
{
    using (var context = new MiContexto())
    {
        foreach (object obj in objs)
        {
            context.sp_insert(obj.campo_1, obj.campo_n);
        }
    }
}
```

Como es habitual, al hacer pruebas en mi equipo local no da ningún error; sin embargo al correr la misma aplicación, con la primer opción, en ambiente de pruebas da el error.

Quisier implementar la primera opción dado que las listas pueden traer miles de registros y me parece que es la opción más óptima.

Cualquier consejo será muy bien recibido.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error se produce cuando se intenta insertar una cadena que excede la longitud máxima del campo donde se está insertando. Revisa la longitud de tus campos de texto para asegurarte que tengan el tamaño suficiente.

```
declare @tabla table (cadena varchar(10))

insert into @tabla values('una cadena que excede el tamaño máximo del campo') --esto produce error
```

Comment: Por eso implementé el insert individual por registro, los valores son exactamente los mismos, y en ese caso no da el error, sólo cuando intento pasar el DataTable